# Rename files in a directory using two separate files. One contains old file names, the other contains new filenames

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I am trying to rename a bunch of files by matching their current filenames from a list and then changing them to new filenames stated in a separate list.

The old filenames are totally random and are all unique. I am looking to change to the file names to something I can better understand.

This is the code I have been trying:

```
import os

old_names = open('/Users/Home/MyLocker/oldnames.txt', 'r').readlines()
new_names = open('/Users/Home/MyLocker/newnames.txt', 'r').readlines()

for (oldname, newname) in zip(old_names, new_names):
    real_oldname = os.path.abspath(oldname.strip())
    real_newname = os.path.abspath(newname.strip())
    os.rename(real_oldname, real_newname)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "../zip.py", line 9, in <module>
   os.rename(real_oldname, real_newname) 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:     '/Users/Home/MyLocker/g-ms6iTwN3wpQAeOx51pWl7AaGpSsbxsptOWBFggD0MMB8SYJayZ0zuGEjvI8Gj8OdrRxzraHwMNW8sgjyaE' -> '/Users/Home/MyLocker/258'
```

The filenames both look correct in the error and I cannot understand why it is not working.

Could anyone help me correct this issue or explain what the problem is please?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that '/Users/Home/MyLocker/g-ms6iTwN3wpQAeOx51pWl7AaGpSsbxsptOWBFggD0MMB8SYJayZ0zuGEjvI8Gj8OdrRxzraHwMNW8sgjyaE' exists? The error seems to say it doesn't.

Comment: My mistake, when I use the ls command there appears to be a ? at the end of each filename. Like g-ms6iTwN3wpQAeOx51pWl7AaGpSsbxsptOWBF‌​ggD0MMB8SYJayZ0zuGEj‌​vI8Gj8OdrRxzraHwMNW8‌​sgjyaE?. This question mark only appears when I use ls. Im not sure why the question mark is there, do you think I could edit my script to accommodate for this or would I be better changing my old names.txt?

Comment: I changed old names.txt to include ? but I got the same error only this time the question mark was included.